# Save canvas with image with points to folder

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, canvas

In a canvas I attach an image, after a click on it a point is drawn to the image and on double click the point is removed. My ultimate goal is to save the image with the points to a folder. Unfortunately only the points are saved in the folder without the image.

How can I fix my codes to save both points and image to the folder ?

```
I- My code to save to the folder

// send to controller
 $('#save').on('click', function() {
  var canvasData1 = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
 $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<?=base_url('admin_medico/SaveCanvas')?>",
data: {canvasData1 :canvasData1}
   });

    });


//Controller

 $file2 = $upload_dir ."fondo-". time() . ".png";
$data2 = $_POST['canvasData1'];
$data2 = substr($data2,strpos($data2,",")+1);
$data2 = base64_decode($data2);
file_put_contents($file2, $data2);
```

2- codes to draw the point on click and remove the point on double click are [in this fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/830391/)

Comment: You need to draw your image onto the canvas! 

right now it is just a background image in the Dom, but not part of any canvas.

Have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

this is from the FF(mozilla docs)

Comment: When I draw the image onto the canvas, it is true that both point and canvas are saved into the folder but I have this issue : after double click on a point to remove it a part of the canvas is removed as well. How can I fix this  ? I updated my fiddle to see what I mean.

Comment: use 2 canvas, one on top of the other or use your current setup with the background image and have this background image drawn in an off-positioned canvas.